# is there a way to keep router query on page refresh in next js when use 'as' in router

Tags: reactjs, next.js

```
<Link href={{pathname:`/category/${(item.slug)}`,query:{cateid:item.id} }}
```

as={`/category/${item.slug}`}>

when I refresh the page, router.query.cateid is lost

Comment: Do you really need `as` at all here? I think you can just remove it in that case.

Comment: If the idea is to use `as` to remove the query params from the URL, then there's no way for you to keep the params available on refresh since they're no longer part of the URL. You could try persisting the params on the client instead.